# how to write BeforeAdvice for Thread Class in a struts application using Spring AOP?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, struts, aop

I am having a struts application using the Spring AOP and IoC via applicationContext.xml loading through ClassPathXmlApplicationContext().

Now am having a Mailer.java which extends a thread as below

```
public class Mailer extends Thread 
{
    public static void sendMessage(String to, String cc, String from, String subject, String message) throws MessagingException
    {
      //sending e-mails, returning nothing
    }
}
```

in the above class the sendMessage() is a static method and is called in sucha a way like

```
Mailer.sendMessage()
```

in the service classes of the application.

Now I want to create a MethodBeforeAdvice for that sendMessage() method. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Spring AOP is proxy based - therefore you need to use the [AspectJ compiler/weaver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `@Aspect` for your advice, the method should be annotated with [`@Before`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-advice) annotation.

```
@Before("execution(* com.package.Mailer.sendMessage(..))")
public void aMethodBeforeAdvice(JoinPoint jp) {}
```